# Keeping <select> as a dropdown with the multiple attribute set

Tags: javascript, html, dom, drop-down-menu

I have written a script that takes a pull down `<select>` on a web page, and adds a `multiple` attribute to the `<select>` so that multiple options can be picked. However, when "multiple" is set my `<select>` element loses its dropdown arrow and turns into a select box with no drop down. Is there any way to set a select to accept multiple options while retaining it as a drop down on the web page? The script is rather long as it uses other information on the page to determine if the `<select>` needs to but multiple or single select, the code which changes this attribute is below.

```
if (Qtype === "Multi-Select") {
  select_elem.setAttribute("multiple", "multiple");
}
if (Qtype === "Single-Select") {
  select_elem.removeAttribute("multiple");
}
```

Comment: share your code snippet also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add the multiple attribute to the select it changes the control to a select box by default (to let the user pick more than one option).

An easy way to get your desired behavior is by using a plugin.

One plugin to do this (there are many more) is: multiple-select.js (It is a jQuery plugin)

[Link to plugin](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#the-basics1)